# Moving Conda Environment to a computer with no Internet Access

Tags: anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I'm trying to reproduce an environment that I've created on my laptop with all the necessary packages to another laptop with no internet access (But Anaconda is already installed on it).
I'm following the instructions form this link https://www.anaconda.com/moving-conda-environments/
which recommends to use `Conda Pack` in this case.
I've followed the instructions as the following:

> 1) downloaded the `conda-pack` on my laptop using the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-pack
```

> 2) packed the environment using the following command:

```
conda pack -n my_env
```

this step produced the file `my_env.tar.gz`

> 3) I copied `my_env.tar.gz` to the laptop with no internet connection and used the command:

```
mkdir -p my_en
```

> 4) unpacked the my_env.tar.gz using the following the command:

```
tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env
```

and here's the problem after the fourth step all that appears in the Anaconda Prompt is the following error:

```
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying
```

and that goes forever, is there an alternative to this method to copy an environment to another offline Computer??

Comment: I'm having the same problem (Windows 10)

Comment: @SeanDoris Unfortunately I didn't find a solution until now

Comment: I did a little troubleshooting, and this only became a problem with certain packages installed in the conda environment (Jupyter, I think? Or maybe something with plotly, I don't remember). I was able to fix this problem by switching compression format to zip, though I abandoned condabin for other reasons so didn't fully explore. Good luck!

Comment: @SeanDoris ah okay! Thanks a lot anyway